# How to calculate sum based on cells that have a specific text next to them?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of prices and sum them up in a cell at the right.

Next to some prices I have the work "select".

**How do I calculate the sum of all prices which next to them have the word "select"?**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the function `Sumifs()`

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"=select")
```

Comment: thanks, this is what worked for me: =SUMIFS(A3:A30;B3:B30;"=select")